# "Preface" appears as header on even pages?

Tags: header-footer

I stumbled a bit at first adding a preface to a book I'm writing. I've got it set up now by adding `\chapter*{Preface}` to `\frontmatter` and  `\addcontentline` to include the preface in the table of contents.

However now the word "preface" appears as a header on the even-numbered pages (instead of the appropriate chapter name), and I can't figure out how to make it stop.

Comment: Welcome to TeX .SX! Could you please post a compilable code  that we can test?

Comment: Thank you  and not yet - I "inherited" all of the pre-\begin{document} formatting commands, and they're a bit of a mess. I'm in the process of cleaning it up, and once I'm done, if the problem persists, I will post it. I can say that the problem did not exist before I attempted to include a preface.

Comment: I figured it out: the command \fancyhead[RE]{\bf preface} found its way into the preamble (I don't know how). I replaced it with \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} and all is well.

Comment: That's quite fine!